# If condition for wordpress multiple featured image plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have setup Multiple featured image plugin. That's work good for me.

My requirement is:

```
if: The Multiple Post Thumbnail Exists
    then: Show the Multiple Post Thumbnail Image
else: Show the Default Featured Image Thumbnail
```

Right now i have displayed multiple featured image using following code:

```
<?php add_image_size('post-big-artful-interiorsimg-fullsize', full);
        if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'big-artful-interiors', NULL, 'post-big-artful-interiorsimg-fullsize'); 
        endif; 
?>
```

and default featured image display using following code:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thevoux-single',array('itemprop'=>'image')); ?>
```

How can I show default featured image if Multiple featured image is not available. Any idea then inform me.

Comment: Try This 

<?php add_image_size('post-big-artful-interiorsimg-fullsize', full);
        if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) { MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'big-artful-interiors', NULL, 'post-big-artful-interiorsimg-fullsize'); 
        }else{
 the_post_thumbnail('thevoux-single',array('itemprop'=>'image'));
}
?>

Comment: Can you please formatting the code and resend. Thanks.

Comment: Is that working for you? then i will add answer!!

Comment: I only like formatted code. So first please format the code then i will test.

Comment: try below code if its works please let me konw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This code

```
<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails') && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', 'big-artful-interiors')) {

add_image_size('post-big-artful-interiorsimg-fullsize', full);
                        MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'big-artful-interiors', NULL, 'post-big-artful-interiorsimg-fullsize');

} else {
    the_post_thumbnail('thevoux-single',array('itemprop'=>'image'));    
} ?>
```

Comment: no that not working. If MultiPostThumbnails image not available then it can't display default featured image.

Comment: Using your code i have applied my logic and if condition works good. 

Thanks.